# Add AngularJS2 plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, angular, eclipse-plugin

I just started learning AngularJS2. I want to plugin AngularJS2 in Eclipse IDE. Please someone suggest me how to do this. I am using Eclipse Mars.

Comment: You should use Eclipse Neon. Some improvements in the JavaScript editor can be useful for AngularJS development.

Comment: Angular2 Eclipse requires Neon because it uses WTP JSON Editor, HTML Validator improvement to ignore error for Angular2 syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular2-eclipse you can install in Eclipse Neon. I don't think it's compatible with Eclipse Mars, but using Neon is worth it anyway.